# Deployed link doesn't show content of my website but localhost does

Tags: reactjs, deployment, background, localhost

so I added a background video component to my contact forum in my website. It runs perfectly fine on localhost but once I run it on the deployed link, I get a white background to my contact forum. I deployed it through AWS

I tried re-hosting it again but nothing changed

Comment: Please mention more things including some related code snippet, live fiddle if possible, here's [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)